# Unable to match quantlib examples

Tags: quantlib

I'm currently learning Quantlib using C++ and am following the very good instructions here:

https://www.quantlib.org/slides/dima-ql-intro-2.pdf

Specifically on building piecewise yieldcurves (slide 102) the example code gives the following output:

```
Settlement Date:September 15th, 2009
Zero 3M: 0.299690 % Actual/360 simple compounding
Zero 6M: 0.682500 % Actual/360 simple compounding
Zero 9M: 0.997500 % Actual/360 simple compounding
```

Yet copying the code verbatim using the header `YieldCurve6.h`, I consistently get the following:

```
Settlement Date:September 15th, 2009
Zero 3M: 0.240698 % Actual/360 simple compounding
Zero 6M: 0.240770 % Actual/360 simple compounding
Zero 9M: 0.240844 % Actual/360 simple compounding
```

Is anyone else able to run the example code within the slides and get matching results?

**Update 1**

As per the comment below, I've put the code here which comes from the code used in the slides:

https://gist.github.com/imrichardcole/2859eccb2240e4c663b64fecf77ed407

Comment: It was not obvious to me and in case it is helpful for others: The code, including YieldCurve6.h, can be found at https://www.quantlib.org/docs.shtml in the Slides section. Here is the direct link to the zip file: https://www.quantlib.org/slides/dima-code.zip.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the slide is not setting the evaluation date, therefore the calculation is done as of 2023, which of course throws it off.  You need to add

```
Settings::instance().evaluationDate() = today;
```

after you define `today` in the code.  This will give you the results in the slide.